# eBay Large Merchant Services - AddFixedPriceItem in C# end to end

Tags: c#, file-transfer, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I am just learning how to integrate with the eBay API and I am struggling to get things working.

So far I can list a single fixed price item using the standard trading API, but I need to be able to bulk upload items so I am investigating the Large Merchant Service API.

Currently my workflow is as follows:

1. Find outstanding jobs and abort them
2. Create a new `CreateUploadJobRequest`
3. Create a new `UploadFileRequest`
4. Create a new `StartUploadJobRequest`
5. Create a new `GetJobStatusRequest`
6. Create a new `DownloadFileRequest`

Everything is going fine (I think) up until step 6. The request fails with a `ProtocolException`.

Up until that point I have been getting `fileReferenceId`'s, `jobId`'s and successful responses. The code I am using to try and do this (nasty looking as it is) is:

```
httpRequest.Headers.Remove("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME");
httpRequest.Headers.Remove("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME");
httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "FileTransferService");
httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "downloadFile");
if (jobStatResp != null)
{
    var ftclient2 = new FileTransferServicePortClient("FileTransferServiceSOAP");
    using (OperationContextScope scope2 = new OperationContextScope(ftclient2.InnerChannel))
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

        DownloadFileRequest downloadReq = new DownloadFileRequest();
        downloadReq.fileReferenceId = jobStatResp.jobProfile[0].fileReferenceId;
        downloadReq.taskReferenceId = jobStatResp.jobProfile[0].jobId;

        DownloadFileResponse downloadResponse = ftclient2.downloadFile(downloadReq);
        FileAttachment attachment = downloadResponse.fileAttachment;
        FileStream fs = File.Create("response"+Guid.NewGuid());
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        writer.Write(attachment.Data);
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

I've gone through in debug mode and I am getting a `fileReferenceID` and `jobID`.

One thought that comes to mind is that there is a problem with the uploaded xml, the only other thing I can think of is that there is an issue with some of my headers, but I can't see what the issue is.

Ideally I could do with help with the following:

1. Best ways of debugging this and getting as much info from the service as possible
2. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if there is additional information required.

---

I have now managed to identify what the issue is so I'll post the solution here for others who might struggle with this.

Within the app.config there needs to be the following attached to the `FileTransferService` endpoint you have configured

```
<mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
</mtomMessageEncoding>
```

Thanks

Comment: I should also mention that the only token I am passing through is the User Auth Token, I haven't passed in the App, cert or dev tokens as the tutorials I have been following having indicated that I should. Not sure if this is part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full working program

https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1338

There is so much code to understand e call LMS services.

To execute requests such as Revise-Add-Relist-End FixedPriceItem via LMS you have to create an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests>
  <Header>
    <SiteID>101</SiteID>
    <Version>835</Version>
  </Header>
  <AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <MessageID>0G86041299</MessageID>
    <Version>835</Version>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">

</Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
[.. other requests ]
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

You can create the ItemType XML using eBay SDK .NET and serializing the ItemType class.
Make sure to add xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" where needed otherwise the parser at eBay will not work.

Zip it with CSharpZipLib and send via uploadEndToEnd method, get the response unzip the response file and parse the response xml.

Comment: the link is dead, is it possible to get the sample program by an other way please ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue to get a fails with a ProtocolException in the step 6 request. I tried kipper_t's solution to add mtomMessageEncoding in app.config, however still got the same fail message.

Finally only the solution below works. Use this function to replace step 6, and the file download success:

[https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1567/~/downloadfile-sample-(xml)-in-c%23](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1567/~/downloadfile-sample-%28xml%29-in-c%23)

Comment: Your link is dead. Is it possible to get the sample by an other way ?